# How to get rid of this annoying green color in tree view in Atom?

Tags: git, themes, atom-editor

[image]
No matter what theme I choose the folders and files in tree view always green-ish.
[Someone already asked a similar question here](https://discuss.atom.io/t/tree-view-icon-color-is-in-green-color-always/24127/3) so I even deleted Git and the tree view is still like that. How to disable this feature of Git (if Git is the reason) or how to get colors back to normal?
Changing a lot of CSS rules is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Green means (as [mentioned here](https://discuss.atom.io/t/file-tree-colors-what-do-they-mean/12770)) new files in a Git repository.

If you have a `.git` subfolder in the parent folder of `__pycache__`, and you don't use Git at all, try and delete it.

Comment: unfortunately I don't have this fold anywhere in my project

Comment: @j_noe It is an hidden folder, so make sure to configure your file explorer to display hidden elements. What is your OS?